# ErrorException Undefined offset: 1, laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I was trying to create an webcam photo capture and submission form which will be stored at the database , In order to convert the base 64 file to png, I am using the following codes : (I am sharing the whole function )

```
 public function testVerificationPost(Request $r){
    $upload_documents = rand().'-'.time().'.'.$r->upload_documents->extension();
    $r->upload_documents->move(public_path('uploads'), $upload_documents);

    // $upload_snapshot = rand().'-'.time().'.'.$r->upload_snapshot->extension();
    // $r->upload_snapshot->move(public_path('uploads'), $upload_snapshot);

    $img = $r->snapShot;
    $folderPath = "uploads/";
  
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
  
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName = uniqid() . '.png';
  
    $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
     
   Verification::create([
        'photo' => $fileName,
        'identity_number' => $r->identity_number,
        'identity_card_document' =>  $upload_documents,
        'user_id' =>session('user_session'),
        'identity_card_type' => $r->identity_card_type,
         
    ]);
    return redirect('/verification');
}
```

In blade file :

```
   <div class="row" style="width: 400px;">
                        <div class="column" id="camera" style="height:150px;width:150px; text- 
                        align:right;"></div>

                        <div class="column" style="height:50px;width:50px;">
                            <input type="button" value="Take a picture" name="upload_snapshot" 
                             id="btPic" onclick="takeSnapShot()" required="required" />
                            <p id="snapShot"></p>
                            <input type="hidden" name="snapShot" class="snapShot">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The script I am using :

```
Webcam.set({
width: 220,
height: 190,
image_format: 'jpeg',
jpeg_quality: 200
});
Webcam.attach('#camera');


takeSnapShot = function () {
Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
    document.getElementById('snapShot').innerHTML = 
        '<img name="upload_snapshot" src="' + data_uri + '" width="180px" height="152px" />';
});
}
```

The error I am getting :

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Index 1 in `$image_type_aux` doesn't exist. `dd($image_type_aux)` to see what it actually contains

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => ""
]     why it;s null

Comment: dd($image_parts) to know that. We can't help you without knowing what is in your variables. You have all the tools needed to debug this issue.

Comment: ok the issue solved, thanks both of you for suggesting dd() check, I had to assign the right class name ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
takeSnapShot = function () {
Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
    $(".image").val(data_uri);
    document.getElementById('snapShot').innerHTML = 
        '<img name="upload_snapshot" src="' + data_uri + '" width="180px" 
  height="152px" />';
   });
  }
```

Instead of

```
takeSnapShot = function () {
 Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
document.getElementById('snapShot').innerHTML = 
    '<img name="upload_snapshot" src="' + data_uri + '" width="180px" height="152px" 
   />';
  });
   }
```